# Question about the circumscription of closed curves

Tags: geometry

Suppose we have a closed curve in $\mathbb{R^2}$ (by closed, I mean something like a circle or a country's borders, that divides the plane in two regions, inner and outer - I am not sure "closed" is the correct term for this; maybe it should be "compact"). It is obvious that there is a circumference such that the curve is entirely inside the circumference.

My question is: is there a way (like an algorithm) to find what is the SMALLEST circumference that contains the curve? I.E., to find its center (finding the radius from there seems easy).

Has this problem been solved? Does anyone have any references that may help point me towards a solution? I don't even know what area of math this fits into (I know its Geometry, but is it Differential Geometry? Topology?), so really anything helps...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the best way to do this would be to sample a suitably high number of points along the boundary of the curve and then use the solution of the bomb problem, also known as the [Minimal enclosing circle](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MinimalEnclosingCircle.html) problem?

Comment: I didn't know about it! Does that theorem prove anyway to find the circle, or does it only prove existence? Also, what area of Geometry is this problem mostly associated with?

Comment: This would probably be algebraic or analytic geometry.